# Craft 3 - Fixing deprecation errors

Tags: templating, craft3, twigextension

I'm used to writing Twig 1 syntax, and since switching to Craft 3 (which uses Twig 2) I keep getting lots of deprecation errors in the control panel.

Is there any reference material that provides the Twig syntax I should be using instead for Craft 3 sites?

Comment: The deprecation errors shown in the control panel should also tell you how to update your syntax accordingly, at least all the ones I have seen did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the launch of Craft 3, Pixel and Tonic have provided some [documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#twig-2) on switching from Craft 2 syntax to Craft 3.